# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. But no indication which package could be causing the error. Using Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, android-virtual-device

I recently upgraded both Dart and Flutter via Android Studio and different issues started creeping out.  I eventually updated the packages particularly the Firebase packages because in the past this resolved my issue.  This time around however, I am stuck and could not run my flutter project on the AVD.

---

From Flutter Doctor:

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-PH)
• Flutter version 1.22.3 at C:\Users\Lester\source\flutter
• Framework revision 8874f21e79 (2 months ago), 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700
• Engine revision a1440ca392
• Dart version 2.10.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:/Users/Lester/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/Lester/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin installed
• Dart plugin version 193.7547
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)   (emulator)

• No issues found!

---

From Flutter run -v:

[+6890 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ +110 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[   +1 ms] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
[        ]    > Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\Lester\AppData\Local  \Temp\gradle4590115280405278581.bin offset 165777 exists? true
[   +2 ms] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to     get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 15s
[   +2 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle   7.0.
[   +1 ms] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

[ +308 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 16.8s)
[+3291 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
       #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)  
       #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)  
       <asynchronous suspension>  
       #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner  /flutter_command.dart:977:18)  
       #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)  
       #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)  
       #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)  
       #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)  
       #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)  
       #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)  
       #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)  
       #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)  
       #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)  
       #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)  
       #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)  
       #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)  
       #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)  
       #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)  
       #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)  
       #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)  
       #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)  
       #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android  /android_device.dart)  
       #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)  
       #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)  
       #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)  
       #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)  

       #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)  
       #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)  
       #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)  
       #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)  
       #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)  
       #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)  
       #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>   (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)  
       #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)  
       #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)  
       #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)  
       #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

---

From pubspec.yaml:

version: 1.0.0+1

```
environment:  
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"  

dependencies:  
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter  


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3  
  flutter_svg: ^0.18.1  
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4  
  firebase_core: ^0.6.0  
  firebase_auth: ^0.19.0+1  
  cloud_firestore: ^0.15.0  
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9  
  websafe_svg: ^1.1.4  
  firebase_storage: ^6.0.0  
  http: ^0.12.2  
  passwordfield: ^0.0.82  
  sqflite: ^1.3.1+1  
  path_provider: ^1.6.14  
  flutter_counter: ^1.0.3  
  flushbar: ^1.10.4  
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0  
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.24  
  flutter_custom_clippers: ^1.1.2  
  badges: ^1.1.3  
  video_player: ^1.0.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think because the version of Gradle you are using has been deprecated by android causing this error. So, change the Gradle version to latest release , clean your all builds using flutter clean command and then try to run project again. Let me know if it solves your problem or not.

Comment: My Gradle version is 4.0.2.  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }

Comment: When I try Open Android Module in Android Studio, I see the next error.

Comment: Android: failed

Comment: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\Lester\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle1869407281770566625.bin offset 166327 exists? true
Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module (210) for constraint platform-runtime -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.0.1

Comment: When I check for updates via Android Studio, it tells me I already have the most latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Had to reinstall Android Studio, install everything else and recreate the project.

Comment: I really don't wanna do that,, there has to be some tiny line to be written in some hidden file that will fix the world

Answer (score 0):

Go to [your_flutter_project]>android>app>build.gradle.

Open `build.gradle` and change `compileSdkVerison` and `targetSdkVersion` to an earlier version. (version 29 worked for me).

Make sure both of them are have been changed to the same sdk version.
and add the dependency to the dependencies section

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming late but for me, I had to upgrade the firebase dependency imported in my "**android/app/build.gradle**", then I updated my **minSdkVersion** from **16**  to **20**. Sync your project, this might help